# Export pdf table to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

How to export pdf table to excel using c# and asp.net? if any can you give me a sample code snippet?

Comment: did you find any solution for your problem? i'm also searching for a solution to extraxt tables from pdfs, but i dont need them to imprt them into an excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

There are various tools out there to try and guess the table but it does not actually exist as a table structure in the PDF, so results will vary.

There is a blog article explaining the issue with extraction of text from PDF files at http://web.archive.org/web/20100628021326/http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/12670/PDF-text